# PySpark: Collect dataframe with nested columns as a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the following nested schema:

```
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ac_failure: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ac_failure_delayed: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- alarm_exit_error: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- alarm_has_delay: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nodes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- battery_status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_manufacture_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_product_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_supported_command_class_list: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- device_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- endpoint_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- partition_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- device_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- device_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_class: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- event_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- imei: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- source: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to collect the row as dictionaries.
I tried:

```
seq = [row.asDict() for row in df2_final.collect()]
```

What i get with this is (sample 1 row):

```
    {'data': Row(ac_failure=None, ac_failure_delayed=None, alarm_exit_error=None, alarm_has_delay='true', nodes=None),
 'device_id': 2,
 'device_type': 'panel',
 'event': 'alarm_state',
 'event_class': 'panel_alarm',
 'event_timestamp': 1586921122886,
 'event_type': 'zone_alarm_perimeter',
 'imei': '9900000000000',
 'operation': 'report',
 'partition_id': 0,
 'source': 'panel'}
```

What can I do to get data as dict as well.
eg:

```
{'data': {ac_failure=None, ac_failure_delayed=None, alarm_exit_error=None, alarm_has_delay='true', nodes=None},
     'device_id': 2,
     'device_type': 'panel',
     'event': 'alarm_state',
     'event_class': 'panel_alarm',
     'event_timestamp': 1586921122886,
     'event_type': 'zone_alarm_perimeter',
     'imei': '9900000000000',
     'operation': 'report',
     'partition_id': 0,
     'source': 'panel'}
```

I would like to have all nested columns as dict instead for pyspark.sql.types.row.
TIA

Comment: use `row.asDict(recursive=True)`

Comment: Thanks @jxc. 
This works:

    seq = [row.asDict(recursive=True) for row in df2_final.collect()]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @jxc.
This works:

```
seq = [row.asDict(recursive=True) for row in df2_final.collect()]
```